# MonoDevelop Error dialog keeps popping up when writing LINQ Query

Tags: linq, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

I have a very annoying problem, while I am writing LINQ queries Mono Develop keeps popping up a message saying that an error has occurred and details will be sent to Xamarin.

It looks like the IDE is parsing my LINQ query while i am writing it, is there a way to turn this off?

Below is the detail of the Exception.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.Refactoring.TypeSystemAstBuilder.ConvertConstructor (IMethod ctor) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/monodevelop/main/contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp/Refactoring/TypeSystemAstBuilder.cs:651 
>     at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.Refactoring.TypeSystemAstBuilder.ConvertEntity (IEntity entity) [0x000a4] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/monodevelop/main/contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp/Refactoring/TypeSystemAstBuilder.cs:429 
>     at MonoDevelop.CSharp.Completion.MemberCompletionData+MyAmbience.ConvertEntity (IEntity entity, IOutputFormatter formatter, ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.CSharpFormattingOptions formattingPolicy) [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Completion/MemberCompletionData.cs:316 
>     at MonoDevelop.CSharp.Completion.MemberCompletionData+MyAmbience.ConvertEntity (IEntity entity) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Completion/MemberCompletionData.cs:302 
>     at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.LanguageItemTooltipProvider.CreateTooltip (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Semantics.ResolveResult result, Int32 offset, MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.Ambience ambience) [0x002d7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Tooltips/LanguageItemTooltipProvider.cs:260 
>     at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.LanguageItemTooltipProvider.CreateTooltipWindow (Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor editor, Int32 offset, ModifierType modifierState, Mono.TextEditor.TooltipItem item) [0x00164] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Tooltips/LanguageItemTooltipProvider.cs:126 
>     at Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor.TooltipTimer () [0x00129] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor/Gui/TextEditor.cs:2602 
>     at GLib.Timeout+TimeoutProxy.Handler () [0x00000] in :0

Comment: I suggest reporting a bug. This is obviously not by design and also not something we can fix by... e.g. telling you to type faster :)

Comment: Is there any way to turn off the dialog popping up every time and prompting me to send a report other than sending a report automatically? It happens so often I'm worried about chewing up data if it sends automatically.